# Hermite Polynomials for |x|

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, special-functions, mathematical-physics

The question is:

Decompose |x| into a series of Hermite polynomials

I have problems in this question because I don't know, which tool should I use. I know that H1=x, then I need to make a linear combination?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Why did you tag "partial-differential-equations" ? I see no PDE in your question.